# Removing a MovieClip after swapping depth

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have some code in **ActionScript 2** similar to the below snippet (`Item` being a MovieClip):

```
_root.createEmptyMovieClip("Temp",_root.getNextHighestDepth());
_root.Item.swapDepths(_root.Temp);  
_root.Temp.removeMovieClip(); // This doesn't work !
```

I think the question is clear. I'm unable to remove `Temp` after swapping the depth (works fine otherwise).

I also tried the following (but to no avail):

```
depth = Item.getDepth();
_root.createEmptyMovieClip("Temp",_root.getNextHighestDepth());
_root.Item.swapDepths(_root.Temp);  
_root.getInstanceAtDepth(depth).removeMovieClip(); // Doesn't work !
```

Any thoughts on how to get rid of `Temp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the hidden reason behind the immortality of `Temp` MovieClip. 
The MovieClip `Item` with which it is swapped was created manually in the timeline. So after swapping, `Temp` is within the [zone of depths](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/depths2.htm) for which Flash doesn't support dynamic removal of symbols.

If I'd swapped depths between `Temp` and `Item1 = Item.duplicateMovieClip("Item1", someDepth);`, the `removeClip()` would've worked!

Answer (score 0):

Please try with given below code:

```
_root.createEmptyMovieClip("Temp",_root.getNextHighestDepth());
_root.Item.swapDepths(_root.Temp);  
removeMovieClip(_root.Temp);
```

if you are creating dynamic movieclip using ActionScript code. then you have to use `removeMovieClip(XXXXXX);` function instead of the `XXXXXX.removeMoveiClip();`

Note :- XXXXXX is a instance reference of MoveiClip which is created runtime using ActionScript 2.0 Code.

Reason: "removeMovieClip() only works for dynamically created movieclips"

Comment: As I have said, the problem occurs after the swapDepths() function. Without that line, XXXXXX.removeMovieClip() works perfectly.

Comment: Yes But after swapping it has Display List Issue in AVM1. So it will be occur. So you have to use removeMovieClip(_root.Temp);
Before swapping it will work. you have to study Array, Display List in ActionScript 2.0 and MovieClip Child Object Management.

Comment: I've updated the actual problem as an answer above. As a matter of fact, I've tried out all possible forms of removeMovieClip() before asking the question!